# Unity Android IL2CPP Build Succeeded But Apk Not Generated

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an Android build with Unity. I changed the Scripting Backend to IL2CPP because of the recent 64 bit support that is mandatory for submitting the app to Google Play after which I checked the ARM64 architecture but I am not able to generate an apk for the same.

EDIT:
My build settings
[image]

My player settings

[image]

I am getting the following error:

```
Failed running C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp/build/il2cpp.exe --convert-to-cpp --emit-null-checks --enable-array-bounds-check --dotnetprofile="unityaot" --compile-cpp --libil2cpp-static --platform="Android" --architecture="ARMv7" --configuration="Release" --outputpath="E:\YouTube\LiveStream\JaiHindISRO\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a\libil2cpp.so" --cachedirectory="E:\YouTube\LiveStream\JaiHindISRO\Assets\..\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a/il2cpp_cache" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\bdwgc/include" --additional-include-directories="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\libil2cpp/include" --tool-chain-path="E:/Android/android-ndk-r16b/android-ndk-r16b" --map-file-parser="C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\MapFileParser\MapFileParser.exe" --directory="E:\YouTube\LiveStream\JaiHindISRO\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Managed" --generatedcppdir="E:\YouTube\LiveStream\JaiHindISRO\Temp\StagingArea\Il2Cpp\il2cppOutput" 

stdout:
Building libil2cpp.so with AndroidToolChain
    Output directory: E:\YouTube\LiveStream\JaiHindISRO\Temp\StagingArea\assets\bin\Data\Native\armeabi-v7a
    Cache directory: E:\YouTube\LiveStream\JaiHindISRO\Library\il2cpp_android_armeabi-v7a\il2cpp_cache
il2cpp.exe didn't catch exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.RunWithResult[D,T](D[] data, Func`2 action)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #1) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #2) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #3) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #4) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #5) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #6) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #7) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #8) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #9) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #10) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

---> (Inner Exception #11) System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)<---

stderr:

Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Shell.Execute(ExecuteArgs executeArgs, IExecuteController controller)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.ProvideObjectFile(IntermediateObjectFileCompilationData data)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.<>c__DisplayClass1_0`2.<RunWithResult>b__0(Object o)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.ParallelFor.RunWithResult[D,T](D[] data, Func`2 action)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.BuildAllCppFiles(IEnumerable`1 sourceFilesToCompile, IBuildStatisticsCollector statisticsCollector)
   at Unity.IL2CPP.Building.CppProgramBuilder.Build(IBuildStatistics& statistics)
   at il2cpp.Program.DoRun(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Run(String[] args)
   at il2cpp.Program.Main(String[] args)

UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunProgram(Program, String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:128)
UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase, Action`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/BuildUtils.cs:73)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunIl2CppWithArguments(List`1, Action`1, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:370)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:ConvertPlayerDlltoCpp(String, String, String, Boolean) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:351)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:35)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of your build settings\

Comment: @MilosRomanic have added the screenshot of build settings in the question

Comment: I was looking more for this window -> https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildSettings.html

Comment: @MilosRomanic oh sorry my bad. Have updated and added the build settings window

Comment: Your build is failing at `UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)`, try other solutions you can find on the internet :D

Comment: What happens if you build it into a much shorter path like e:\tmp

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the Build System option in Build settings to internal :D